# How to reindex a particular node in Drupal 8?

Tags: nodes, 8, hooks, search

I want to index particular node on update, insert how to do it in Drupal 8?

In drupal 7, we use the function `function _node_index_node()`

I want to use the same function in drupal8 for my Drupal 8 Site.

I have searched the drupal 8 change log, I have got [`NodeSearch::indexNode()`] function.
I have inherited node search in my class and used the above mentioned function but i get an error  "class not found" .

Is anyone familiar with this function? Please provide me inputs on how to do this in drupal 8.
I am new to Drupal 8.